# Eclipse Jasper report in Java Swing Application

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jasper-reports

Good Day, I have created a Java GUI with Eclipse(Java JDK 1.8.0_31 & Eclipse 4.4.1). So then I have installed Jasper report v6 in my same project and created jasper report inside my project.

It is generating report and opening Jasper Viewer window.
See the code below;

DB.java

```
package jasper1;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DB {
Connection conn = null;
public static class database {
public static String host;
public static String db;
public static String user;
public static String pwd;
}

public static Connection Connector(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+database.host+":3306/" +database.db ,database.user,database.pwd);
        return conn;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed.\n" +  e);
        return null;
                }
}

}
```

form1.java

```
package jasper1;

import jasper1.DB.database;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class form1 {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    form1 window = new form1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Connection conn = null;
    private JTextField text_Host;
    private JTextField text_DB;
    private JTextField text_User;
    private JTextField text_Pwd;

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public form1() {
        initialize();

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Connect");
        btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                btnNewButton.setText("Please wait...");
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                btnNewButton.setText("Connect");
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                database.host = text_Host.getText();
                database.db = text_DB.getText();
                database.user = text_User.getText();
                database.pwd = text_Pwd.getText();

                conn = DB.Connector();

                if(conn != null){
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Connected");
                    String reportPath = "reports/report.jrxml";
                    try {
                        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath);
                        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, conn);
                        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, conn);
                        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
                        conn.close();


                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
                    }



                    return;

                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(73, 167, 130, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        text_Host = new JTextField();
        text_Host.setText("localhost");
        text_Host.setBounds(93, 32, 110, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(text_Host);
        text_Host.setColumns(10);

        text_DB = new JTextField();
        text_DB.setText("qatarclean");
        text_DB.setBounds(93, 63, 110, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(text_DB);
        text_DB.setColumns(10);

        text_User = new JTextField();
        text_User.setText("root");
        text_User.setBounds(93, 94, 110, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(text_User);
        text_User.setColumns(10);

        text_Pwd = new JTextField();
        text_Pwd.setText("supun123");
        text_Pwd.setBounds(93, 125, 110, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(text_Pwd);
        text_Pwd.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblHost = new JLabel("Host");
        lblHost.setBounds(38, 31, 46, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblHost);

        JLabel lblDatabase = new JLabel("Database");
        lblDatabase.setBounds(38, 63, 56, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblDatabase);

        JLabel lblUserName = new JLabel("User Name");
        lblUserName.setBounds(38, 94, 67, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblUserName);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        lblPassword.setBounds(38, 125, 56, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);
    }
}
```

The questions are:

1. Is there any way to view this report inside my form object?.
2. How can I compile this to one file to work in cross platform? I tried to export it to .Jar(Executable Jar) file. But it doesn't include report.jrxml. It is not secure to keep jrxml file outside because it's user readable. How can I compile the project more secure?
3. What are the exact Jasper Library jar files to add in the project? I have added all jars in `jasperreports-6.0.0\dist` and `jasperreports-6.0.0\lib`. When I export it to Executable Jar, file size will be more than 50MB.

If anyone has alternate solution like BIRT Reports, Kindly answer these questions instead of Jasper Reports.